# Postgresql recording datetimes incorrectly with Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, datetime

So I have the following data that I want to save which begins in the following format:

```
2015-07-26T17:00:00-0700
```

In one of the views of my application I take the above time using `parser`:

```
from dateutil import parser
date = parser.parse('2015-07-26T17:00:00-0700')
```

This returns:

```
2015-07-26 17:00:00-07:00
```

The idea was to make it a DateTime object. After this I save it to my datebase like so:

```
  d = Events(name=event["name"],
           location=event["location"],
           description=event["description"],
           event_time=date,
           end_time=event.get("end_time", 'None'),
           eventimage_url=event["cover"]["source"])
  d.save()
```

Then when I query the database

```
event_list = Events.objects.all()
print event_list[0].event_time ## There is only one record in the database
```

I get the following:

```
2015-07-27 00:00:00+00:00
```

It looks like Postgresql is rounding up the time in my database and I don't want it to do this.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'MY_APPLICATION',
        'USER': 'MY_NAME',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Here are the statements used to create my database:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "App_events" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "location" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "description" varchar(10000) NOT NULL, "event_time" timestamp with time zone NOT NULL, "end_time" varchar(128) NOT NULL, "eventimage_url" varchar(300) NOT NULL);
COMMIT;
```

And this is how my model is designed:

```
class Events(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  description = models.CharField(max_length=10000)
  event_time = models.DateTimeField()
  end_time = models.CharField(max_length=128)
  eventimage_url = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It's not rounding up.  It's converting to UTC.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the time is correct and there is nothing wrong - the time in the database server is being given back to you in UTC (because it is set to store it in that manner) instead of -7 - if you set it to the proper timezone you will no longer have an issue - but it is generally best practice to store in UTC

You can set any retrieved value to any timezone using a library like pytz

```
from pytz import timezone
my_adjusted_date = timezone(valid_timezone).localize(datetime_value)
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that has a similar problem you have to change the `TIME_ZONE` in your `setting.py` file. Use from the TZ column [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: That is a solution as well if you expect to always store info in a specific Timezone always.